# Expectation of absolute difference between a random variable with its median

Tags: expected-value, median

Given a random variable $x \sim p(x)$. Denote $m$ to be the median of x.
What is the expected value of $|x-m|$, i.e we would like to compute the following integral:
$$\int |x-m| p(x)dx $$

Comment: There is no general solution to this expectation. If the distribution is symmetric with finite mean, it will be 0. Otherwise, it's some constant.

Comment: @AdamO You seem to have not seen the absolute value signs in the integrand.

Comment: @whuber right. even more intractable then.

Answer (score 0):

The expected value will differ, depending on the distribution.  *However* whatever that value may be, it will be the minimum possible value over all possible choices for *m* -- that is in fact one way of defining the median.  No other choice of *m* will result in a lower expected value.